# Install4j: Howto use String arrays in textfields

Tags: textfield, arrays, install4j

In my installer there is a screen with **textfields** whitch appears **several times in a loop** to configure different instances of services. For cleanliness i want to **save those values in a String array**.

**How do i bind the specific index of the array to the texfield?
What do i write into the 'variable name' field of the textfield?**

I've tried all possible combinations like `${installer:vars[0]}`, but none of them worked.

Comment: will you plz let us know in which technology your working?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of binding is not possible directly. You have to bind the text field to a temporary variable, say `tempVar` and in the validation expression of the screen you have to push it into a list variable, say `myList` with the following code:

```
List values = (List)context.getVariable("myList");
if (values == null) {
    values = new ArrayList<String>();
    context.setVariable("myList", values);
}
values.add(context.getVariable("tempVar"));
```